# Creating a Docker container to deploy a Python application

Tags: python, linux, docker

## Current Problem

I am trying to productionize a Python application. This is not easy because Python does not support a way of creating a single compiled binary from the source code. Furthermore Python does not support a natural way of creating shared libraries. I will explain this in further detail in the following section.

### Python and Shared Libraries

Most languages offer some relatively convenient way of productionizing code. This usually involves:

- Creating some shared libraries containing code which is common to a project
- Creating executable files which use the shared libraries (and maybe other libraries)

Examples:

- Java has a way to bundle code into a `.jar` file. There are tools like Maven and Gradle to assist with the process of deployment and bundling.
- With languages like C++ and C, typically one builds binary libraries and binary executable files. These can then be deployed. There is a way to link a binary executable such that it contains all the shared library code.
- Rust has Cargo which typically builds individual binary executables containing all relevant code.

Python works a bit differently, because the interpreter process only knows about the current working directory path and any paths which have been added to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

- Modifying the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable isn't generally advisable as it doesn't scale well and results in an additional overhead in maintaining its value.

This means that either;

- Python executables must be a single file and there can be no shared code between executables
- or, any shared code has to go in a libary which must be placed in the same current working directory as the executables themselves

This suggests a project structure like this:

```
my-project/
  bin/
    executable1.py
    executable2.py
    ...
    lib1/
      __init__.py
      ...
    lib2/
      __init__.py
      ...
```

Clearly we don't build projects like this. Putting all the shared library code in the same directory as executable files is already weird enough. The stucture also breaks if we want to have shared library code and multiple directories under `bin` for different "groups" of executables. For example, it is not possible to create two subdirectories under `bin` called `group1` and `group2` and share common Python code in a shared library used by both groups.

**This is why I say *Python does not support shared libraries*.** You can build a shared library, but you need to use some other tool to do it. (Unless you resort to modifying `PYTHONPATH`. Let's assume we don't want to do that.)

### Solutions to Python Shared Libraries Problems

In reality, we would use a tool like virtualenv (venv) or Poetry (which essentially manages virtualenvs) to allow us to defer common library code to some other directory, and to enable the Python interpreter to find it.

## My current workflow situation

Until now, I have been using venv in interactive mode to develop Python software.

This means that I have a project structure like this

```
my-project
  .venv/...
  bin/
    ...
  src/
    lib1/...
    lib2/...
  pyproject.toml
```

and I have been using the venv in interactive mode:

```
$ .venv/bin/activate
$ pip3 install -e .
```

This is great for development, because if the library code under `src` is changed, those changes show up "live". (Meaning there is no bundle, install step required. Just run the executable and the "current" code is in use.)

It isn't so good for deployment.

## Why Docker?

My first approach to trying to "install" a production ready version of the code was to do the following:

- Use `systemd` to manage processes (starting and stopping)
- Copy the executable code from the `bin` folder to some "deployment" location on the system (for example `/opt/my-project/bin/`)
- Build a wheel (`.whl`) file
- Install the `whl` system-wide

I did not get as far as the final two steps, as I realized this was probably not a good approach. There are some problems with this:

- The point of using a virtual environment was to avoid having to install packages with `pip` system wide. It therefore doesn't make a lot of sense to create a `whl` and install that system wide.
- I also do not know how I would use a virtual environment in this context. I described copying the executable Python files to some directory like `/opt` which is (obviously) outside of the "development" directory which contains the `.venv`.
- This whole idea doesn't seem to make a lot of sense

**This leads me to believe using Docker results in a much more sensible approach.** We *can* install a `whl` system-wide inside a Docker container.

- On reflection, I actually don't think there is a sensible way to productionize and deploy Python code *without using Docker*. If anyone has any thoughts on that it would be great to get some feedback.

## The Docker Approach and Current Issues

I don't currently understand how to create a Docker image and how to install a `whl` file into it.

Here's how I think the process should work:

1. Build the Python Shared Libraries Code into a Wheel
2. Create a Docker container using a Python distribution image as a base
3. Copy the Wheel to the Docker container
4. Install the Wheel within the Docker container
5. Copy remaining executable Python code to the Docker container (where should it go?)
6. Set the default entry point of the Container to be one of the Python executables
7. There are then additional questions about "nice extras", for example adding to the `PATH` or possibly renaming a `.py` executable so that it looks like a regular executable... maybe?

The reason I am confused is that I am using Poetry to manage the virtual envs for the development process (these are not needed in the production Docker image) and I do not understand how to perform the above steps becuase the Docker container will not have a venv or Poetry installed. But I am using both to run my code during the development process. (Outside of the Docker container.)

Here's what I have in a `pyproject.toml` right now:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "docker-python-poetry-example"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Example <example@example.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
example-executable = 'bin.example_executable:main'

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I am confused because I do not understand where and when I should be using Poetry. Does the Docker container need Poetry installed to install the wheel? I don't think it should have this.

Comment: This question is probably too broad for SO. You should clarify what you mean by "productionize": do you want users to use your application? do you want to deploy it somewhere? *This is not easy because Python does not support a way of creating a single compiled binary from the source code.* - There are ways to create executable from Python code, check [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) for instance.

Comment: This is very very very very long. Can you summarize what is the question in 3 sentences? `how to split the virtual env development process from the Docker container production process - if that makes any sense?` I do not undestand the question. How is it "joined"?

Comment: Sure - so to answer both questions. Imagine I have a development machine where I am working on some Python project consisting of multiple executable Python scripts and a set of shared libraries, which can only be shared with the development executables if they are managed by a venv. (I have set it to be in editable mode.) The question is, how can I easily deploy that code to another machine, start and stop it running.

Comment: I think Docker is a good way to do this. As described in the question, I think the way it should be done is like this: 1. Build the library code into a wheel. 2. Create a Docker container image, install that wheel into it, somehow. 3. Copy the executable python scripts  to the docker container. 4. You are done. We now have a Docker container image containing everything we need.

Comment: Have you read the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/)?  This discusses many of the points you describe here.  To the extent that you could, say write a Java library _in a separate source tree_ and import its `.jar` file into a Java project, you can similarly write and package Python libraries.  I might not necessarily reach for Docker as my first tool here, though a Python package that uses the Python-native tools well can translate easily into a Docker image.

Answer (score 1):

> how to create a Docker image and how to install a whl file into it.

You install, build, do everything inside the docker image. You only copy the source code, on a fresh, unmodified repository without any new files. The idea is so that it is *self-contained*, *reproducible* and research other buzzwords.

```
FROM python
COPY . .
RUN pip install -e .
```

Done. Usually install requirements.txt first to cache dependencies in docker layers for faster builds.

I have no idea about poetry, `pip` is the standard tool that I use. For poetry, editable install according to docs is done with `poetry add --editable .`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be simpler than I origionally thought.

I think Poetry is only needed outside of the Docker container, and that inside the container, the container has no use of it.

This is what I have come up with.

Firstly, the sequence of commands which must be run:

```
# build the .whl using Poetry
poetry build

# build the Docker container from the Dockerfile
docker build -t example-container .
```

Here's the updated `Dockerfile`:

```
from python:3.12-bookworm
workdir /opt/docker-python-poetry-example

# copy the whl, and install it system-wide, inside the Docker container
copy dist/*.whl /opt/docker-python-poetry-example
run pip install *.whl
run rm /opt/docker-python-poetry-example/*.whl

# copy the executable "binaries" (Python scripts), add this dir to `PATH`
copy bin /opt/docker-python-poetry-example/bin
run chmod +x /opt/docker-python-poetry-example/bin/*
env PATH="/opt/docker-python-poetry-example/bin:${PATH}"

# entry point
cmd example_executable.py
```

It seems to work.

## Here's why I think this is a sensible approach:

- We want to distribute some Python code (libraries)
- Normally this would be done by building a wheel, which can be uploaded to pypy for others to use, or just copied to a target machine to be installed with pip
- In this case, we bundle the wheel and executable Python "binaries" together inside a Docker container image
- The Docker image is easy to distribute, start and stop. It is a self contained "thing" or "package"

## What I think the shortcomings are:

- There way library code is distributed and binaries are distributed is different
- There should ideally be a unified approach where both code elements are treated the same way
- Libaries are distributed via a wheel
- Binary code is just copied over

I personally think the requirement of treating libraries and binaries differently is a shortcoming.

- The manual step of updating the `PATH` is perhaps also a shortcoming. It might be better to install the binaries somewhere else?